# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'File 'Test.py' not found in language's search path: .'

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

Whenever I run this script, I get an error as:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'File 'Test.py' not found in
>   language's search path: .'

```
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("Test.py");
test.Simple();//Simple is a method in the python script
```

Comment: Is the file really present in the directory `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`? Maybe output the current directory as a check.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to Test.py properties window and change the "**Copy to Output directory**" to "**Copy Always**".